# How to use both 'insert into' and 'values' in one statement

Tags: sql, database, select, insert

I'd like to join 2 tables together. TableB has 15 distinct values that I want to go into the TableA (the one I'm inserting into). However, I also want to insert individual values for TableA. For example, I want to insert the 15 individual values from TableB into TableA, but I also want to be able to insert another field ('region') in TableA

```
 --so far I have this
 insert into TableA ((id)
      select distinct(id) from TableB
      group by id), region values('NYC')
```

I'm not sure how to insert the region in there...the above fails. I need to hardcore the regions in there because they are not in the other table.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
insert into TableA (id, region)
select distinct id, 'NYC'
from TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ID, REGION)
SELECT ID, 'NYC'
FROM TableB
GROUP BY ID
```

That's it.

The `DISTINCT` is redundant.

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't necessarily redundant, e.g. if id is not a primary key.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` does indeed make it 100% redundant.  I'd be intrigued to see duplicate `id` values when  you group by `id`...

Comment: Ah, you're right there. I just went the other way and took out the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
insert into TableA (id, region)
    select distinct id, "NYC"
    from TableB
    group by id
```